# How do I position a watermark so that it looks good and does not spoil my image?

Tags: watermark

I was just editing [one](http://www.flickr.com/photos/iramkhan/7137195521/) of my pics yesterday using Adobe Lightroom and watermarking it after I had finished editing it. I tried out different positions and angles while placing the watermark but most of them seemed to either block something or the other in the image or not allow the watermark to be seen otherwise. Could you suggest me what to look out for while positioning my watermark so that it does not spoil my work and looks good at the same time?

Comment: IMO, watermarks are overrated and intrusive. Any pixel pusher can get rid of it in Photoshop, unless you make it look like iStock.com watermark or something really obvious. In that case watermark dominates and if you are trying to sell it is a bad idea to use one. I post all my images watermark-free and [use services to find if anyone stole from me.](http://chrismartino.com/blog/2012/01/how-to-find-stolen-photos).

Comment: To be honest, I completely agree with you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most people use watermarks to prevent the photo from being used by other people without consent. The best way to do it is to have it on the [actual subject itself](http://i.istockimg.com/file_thumbview_approve/18888489/2/stock-photo-18888489-nelson-mandella.jpg), but at a very low opacity. Once the photographer decides to sell/give the photograph away, he can always share the hi-res image without the watermark.

Having said that, it you want to have a watermark just to identify your images, then you can place it in a corner and reduce the opacity to about 10-15% so that it does not distract you from the image ([example](https://flic.kr/p/aZc38z)). Another thing you can do is to have a frame around the image and put your watermark there ([example](https://flic.kr/p/bjPGwv)).

Comment: Frames are easily cropped out. So if you are serious about protecting the image, I wouldn't advise a watermark on the edges or frame. Nice answer Vaishak.

Answer (score -1):

I've read many posts about placing a watermark, and mostly they say it should be in the corner that is opposite of your subject. Watermark shouldn't get the most of your attention when you take a look at the photo.

Comment: Please do not post links to your own content without attribution.